# Azure Media Services, Encode custom width and height using PHP SDK

Tags: php, azure, azure-media-services

How can I make custom dimension on Azure Media Service using php sdk
like 640X360 at 650 fps and 960X540 at 1500 fps

Answer (score 0):

According the document on Github at https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php#encode-asset about **Encode asset**, you can try to configure task presets for MES (Media Encoder Standard) via：

```
$mediaProcessor = $this->restProxy->getLatestMediaProcessor('[Media processor]');

$task = new Task('[Task XML body]', $mediaProcessor->getId(), TaskOptions::NONE);
$task->setConfiguration('[Configuration name]');

$restProxy->createJob(new Job(), array($inputAsset), array($task));
```

And you can refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt269926.aspx for a sample of task preset xml content.

Answer (score 0):

Media Encoder Standard can take custom Presets in the setConfiguration call.  You can send in XML or JSON. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/mt269960.aspx

Presets are also stored in GitHub. 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-media-services-samples/tree/master/Encoding%20Presets/VoD/Media%20Encoder%20Standard

Comment: I couldn't send JSON, but XML worked in the setConfiguration call.